# Pass value from a table into a function using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was trying to pass the variable `thecode`, which is in the table using jquery into the function named `getComments()`. My code has as following. First I have my jquery script which is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                           
    $("#comment_process").click(function(){
        if($("#comment_text").val() != ""){ 
         $('.post_loader').show();
            $.post("comments_business.php?action=post", { 
                comment: $("#comment_text").val() 
            }, function(data) {
                $(".comments").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#comment_text").val("");
                $('.post_loader').hide();
            });
        } 
    });   
});
```

Next I have the following script with html and php:

```
<!--- more code at the top---->
<?php $auto = $profile_data_business['business_code'];  ?>
<table>                             
    <textarea rows="3"  id="comment_text" placeholder="share an update."></textarea>
    <input type="" id="comment_code" name="thecode"  value="<?php echo $auto; ?>" />                            
    <input type="button" id="comment_process" /> 
</table>
<div class="comments"><?php include_once("comments_business.php");?>   </div>
```

the page named `comments_business.php` includes a function which is the following:

```
<?php
function getComments(){     
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $comments = "";
    // can't get variable $thisemail
    $thisemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thecode']);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments_business WHERE ( `flag`=0 and `user`='$thisemail' and  `comments_id` NOT IN (SELECT `comments_id` FROM `hide_comment_business` where `user`='$session_user_id') ) ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT 40") or die (mysql_error());
    //more code here            
    return $comments;       
}   
?>
```

Any idea how should I change my jquery code so that I will be able to pass `$thisemail` variable successfully into `getComments()` function?

Comment: question is, how/where are you calling the `getComments()` function and has the session been started?

Comment: yes the session has started

Comment: you also don't have a type in `<input type="" id="comment_code" name="thecode"` it's blank. check for errors, check your console.

Comment: it is type="hidden" but I left it empty so that I could see if it passes the value

Comment: @33528  If your problem solved and my answer were useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

- When you use `$.post` don't need to write `GET` parameter in URL       (action=post).
- When you post data by *comment* name, you must get data by some name
      in `php` (`$_POST['comment']`).
- When you use `ajax` shouldn't use `function` in `php` or call `function`
      after defintion.
- When you use `ajax` must `print` or `echo` data in `php` file to display in
      post result.